# Basic htaccess question, redirect middle dir

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I want to redirect/rewrite a middle directory 'test' (removing it)

```
RewriteRule ^test(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/test/([^/]+)(?:/.*)?$ /$1
```

test url: https://my.domain/en-us/test/my/cool/path

target url: https://my.domain/en-us/my/cool/path

but no variations seem to work. 
htaccess, redirects are working in general

This question has been asked so many times, but they all point to these two answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what worked for me

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)test/(.*)?$ /$1$2 [L,R=301]
```